# Access object that is created in another class

Tags: java

I don't know if this is possible, and that is why I need your help.
What I want to do is that I want to add objects to a Vector. The problem is that the objects are created in another class.
Is it possible?

Here is my code:

```
class Factory {    

    public Factory() {                       
        Action run = new RunAction();
        Action climb = new ClimbAction();
    }
}



public class Game {

    private Vector<Action> actions = new Vector<Action>();

    public  Game(Factory fact) {

        actions.add(XXXX);   ****//What to write here to add the actions created in Factory? Somehow I want to use fact for this.**

     }
 }


 class ClimbAction extends Action {

     public ClimbAction() {
         super("Try to climb\n");
     }
 }


 class RunAction extends Action {

     public RunAction() {
         super("Try to run\n");
     }
 }


 class TestClass {

      Factory f = new Factory();
      Game game = new Game(f);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your factory class to this:

```
class Factory {    

    private Action run;
    private Action climb

    public Factory() {                       
        run = new RunAction();
        climb = new ClimbAction();
    }

    public Action getRunAction(){ return run; }
    public Action getClimbAction(){ return climb; }
}
```

From that, you can access `run` and `climb` through a provided instance of the factory class. e.g. `factory.run`.

Your code defines the two variables `run` and `climb` only in the scope of the Factory class' constructor. Therefore, they can only be accessed from there.

**EDIT**

Also, you seem to want to add all the actions from the Factory to your game. I would therefore advise you add a vector of actions to your factory and add the `run` and `climb` actions through the constructor:

```
class Factory {    
    private Vector<Action> actions = new Vector<Action>();

    public Factory() {                       
        actions.add(new RunAction());
        actions.add(new ClimbAction());
    }

    public Vector getActions(){ return actions; }
    public void setActions(Vector v){ actions = v; }
}

public class Game {

    private Vector<Action> actions = new Vector<Action>();

    public  Game(Factory fact) {
        //add every action in factory to game actions.
        for(Action a : fact.getActions())
            actions.add(a);
     }
}
```

I hope this helped!

Comment: If you downvote, can you at least take the time to drop a comment why please.

Comment: Yes, I want to add all the actions to the Vector. Thank you for your advice, this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Your `Factory` class is not very useful yet: It creates two objects on construction...which can be garbage collected immediately.

Consider a Factory class like this:

```
final class Factory {    

    public [static] Action createRun() {                       
        return new RunAction();
    }

    public [static] Action createClimb() {
       return new ClimbAction();
    }
}
```

This class looks a little more "Factory-Pattern-like", and it(static)/an instance can be used to populate your vector.

Answer (score 1):

Create [variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) in the Factory class, and provide access to them (below demonstrates doing so by defining the variables as private, with access via a getter methods).

```
class Factory {    

    private Action run;//Access modifier is private
    private Action climb;

    public Factory() {                       
        run = new RunAction();
        climb = new ClimbAction();
    }
    public Action getRunAction(){
        return run;
    }
    public Acti8on getClimbAction(){
        return climb;
    }
}
```

In the Constructor, use the getter methods of Factory to access the variables:

```
public  Game(Factory fact) {

    actions.add(fact.getRunAction());   ****//What to write here to add the actions created in Factory? Somehow I want to use fact for this.**

 }
```

Comment: Thanks, this could do it!